# Can't access PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have MAMP server installed on my Macbook and everything worked fine, until I tried to add a password to the 'root' user of localhost. I selected a password and now whenever I go to localhost:8888/phpmyadmin, the page gives me an error saying:

## 1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

It also says that the system tried connecting to MySQL, but MySQL rejected the connection and I have to check my username and password settings.

Why is it acting so weird and how can I get my PHPMyAdmin back to work?

It says I need to check the config.inc.php file, but I can't find that file in the MAMP folder.

Comment: try to log in with the actual mysql utility in a terminal. `> mysql -uroot -pYourPassWordHere` (note: no space between -u/-p and the arguments for them) Does that work? If not, it's not PHPMyAdmin, it's your mysql user table: you never granted access to the root account on localhost.

Comment: It says command not found in the terminal

Comment: that's impressive. How did you install a *AMP stack without mysql getting installed propertly?

Comment: I installed it with the installer (its MAMP free version). I started it up and it turned on Apache and MySQL. I went to localhost:8888/phpmyadmin and looked around without any problems. On the security page of localhost:8888, I changed my password and that's when this all started...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the config file should be under:
/Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin-X.X.X/config.inc.php

Edit it and verify the username//password used

You can always reset the root password using :

http://www.tech-otaku.com/local-server/resetting-mamp-mysql-root-user-password/

Comment: What do I do with that file? So if I change the password there, will everything work fine?

Comment: Look at the link I have posted. it's a nice step by step walk through on how to reset MySQL root password. Once you get the mySQL command line working again, then check phpMyAdmin

Comment: Yeah I've checked out the link you provided, went through all the steps and created a new password using the terminal commands on that website. After that I opened the config.inc.php file and changed the password in that file from root to the password I want to use. Now it works fine. Thank you!

Comment: I've got a little problem though. Every time I start MAMP, I get a warning that connecting to MySQL doesn't work. PHPMyAdmin works fine, but my application doesn't connect to the database, even though I've updated the password in my connection.php file. Why is MAMP giving me a warning?

Comment: can you connect to mysql using cli and the username and password of your application config file?

Comment: With cli you mean Command Line Interface? I don't know, I usually never work with the Command Line Interface. The application doesn't connect to the database with the correct information in my application config.php file.

Comment: Hey Jean, I fixed it now. My URL's in the code were still all 'http://localhost', but I had to change them to 'http://localhost:8888'. It works like a charm now, thanks again!